# Possibility of conflict in multithreading in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have started to concurrency programming in C++.

1. if I have some threads that allocating new memory using "new" is it possible to conflict together?
2. Is there any good reference for pthread? (I know "C++ Concurrency in Action Practical Multithreading Anthony Williams" but it based on C++11)

Comment: 1. No, it is safe. 2. Google for "posix threads".

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not possible for the memory allocation to conflict, as the system is designed to handle such operations and furthermore, it is even possible to allocate memory in one thread and de-allocate it in another.
2. I think your best resources/friends for pthreads will be stack overflow and google

Answer (score 1):

Whether memory allocation is thread safe depends on your compiler/standard library implementation.

With gcc and clang, memory allocation will be thread safe if compiled with -pthreads. With Visual Studio, it will only be thread safe if you link with a multi-threaded runtime (which is the default).